# How to get the mangled symbol of a function in C++?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dlopen

##### Context

I'm using dlmopen to load multiple instance of a shared library which I can't modify (proprietary). I do this because this library is not thread-compatible, so I need an independent version of it to be loaded for each thread.

`void *handle = dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, "/myLib.so", RTLD_LAZY);`

In order to get the function I need, I call dlsym :

`void * test_load = dlsym(handle, <function_symbol>);`

My question is :

##### How do i get <function_symbol> knowing that :

- My library is in C++ (aka the function symbol is mangled)
- I can't modify the library (aka no `extern "C"` to get a predicable symbol)

I know that dlopen/dlmopen is initialy meant to be used in C, not C++, but unless there is an other way to load many time the same shared library, I am stuck

Comment: You'll have to check the documentation for your compiler or C++ library to see if it offers a function that mangles symbols for you.

Comment: You can open the shared library and look at the symbol names inside manually (not portable, but it will give you all the names). Have a look at the command `nm` on linux (to dump the symbol table) or `otool` on mac.

Comment: If it's not your library, you can't rely on the mangled name being stable. There's literally nothing preventing even the same compiler from changing mangled names between versions.

Comment: I don't know about `dlsym`, but in Windows you can load functions by index which might work better for you if the function indexes are more stable.

Comment: @Blindy yeah, I 100% agree, that's why I'm mainly looking for a way to get the symbol on the go. I also know that I use a version of the lib that won't change so I don't expect it's API to change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do i get <function_symbol> knowing that

Presumably you know *which* function you want to call. Let's say its name is `somelib::Init(int, char**)`.

1. Find that function address:
   `nm -CD libsomelib.so | grep 'somelib::Init\(int, char\*\*\)`.
   This should produce something like `12345fa T somelib::Init...`
2. Find its mangled name of that symbol: `nm -D libsomelib.so | grep '^12345fa '`.
   This should produce something like `12345fa T _ZN7somelib4InitEiPPc`.

Use the mangled name in the `dlsym` call.

---

There is no way to map `somelib::Init(int, char**)` to its mangled name because that mapping is not a 1:1 and depends on the exact compiler used to build `libsomelib.so`.

Comment: Damn that's working ! 
To anyone who have the same issue I also give you this very complete tutorial "how to dlopen in C++", that's good material : https://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/intro.html