# Is it possible to expose a set of C++ functions from a shared library?

Tags: c++, linker, c++17, shared-libraries

I have a shared library and a set of functions that i want to be exposed from that shared library.
The functions are C++ functions i.e. they are not `extern c`.

Someone suggested me to use namespace and have a linker script that exposes that namespace. I did not really understand what that means and google is of not much help here.

is it possible to expose C++ functions in a namespace directly from a shared lib such that when someone DLOpens the SO, it becomes available in that application under the said name space automatically?

Tool chain: Clang-12
OS: Linux based
Build system: Cmake

Comment: By expose you mean to be able to dynamically load it with `dlsym(handle, "myFunctionName"`? Then maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73549652/4165552 ?

Comment: You have to provide more information on your operating system, C++ compiler, and linker. At least on Linux with gcc and libtool all global symbols get exported by default from created shared libraries.

Comment: Yes it is (and a namespace is not necessary - in fact it would probably complicate things, for your first effort)

Comment: If you don't use `extern "C"`, your function names are *mangled*, which means any user who wishes to `dlsym` them needs to know how to obtain their mangled names. Mangled names may look like _ZN3Foo3fn1Ev.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to expose a set of C++ functions from a shared library?

Yes. Not only that, but it will happen *by default* if you don't do anything.

> Someone suggested me to use namespace and have a linker script that exposes that namespace.

You *could* do that, although using the `namespace` is probably a distraction. It is certainly not required.

Let's assume that you have this source:

```
namespace Foo {
int fn1() { return 42; }
void fn2() {}
}

void fn3() {}
```

and that you want to make all functions in `namespace Foo` exported from your shared library, but keep functions which are *not* in `namespace Foo` as internal.

```
clang++ -fPIC -c f.cc
nm f.o | grep Foo

0000000000000000 T _ZN3Foo3fn1Ev
0000000000000010 T _ZN3Foo3fn2Ev
```

As you can see, functions within the `namespace Foo` are easy to recognize. The linker version script you'll want then is:

```
{
   global: _ZN3Foo*;
   local: *;
};
```

Putting it all together:

```
clang++ -fPIC f.o -Wl,--version-script=f.lds -shared  -o f.so
nm -D f.so
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000001100 T _ZN3Foo3fn1Ev
0000000000001110 T _ZN3Foo3fn2Ev
                 w __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w __gmon_start__
```

QED.